# How to install a Mozilla Firefox addon for all users on RDP server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, firefox

We have Windows 2008 RDP server with Mozilla Firefox 57.0.1 64 bit installed. How to install an addon for all users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installed the addon using this manual: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Alternative_distribution_options/Add-ons_in_the_enterprise

Comment: Doesn't really explain which method you used. The standard extension folder is one of the options there, too. At least explain how you solved this.

Comment: @EsaJokinen  
Standard extension folder method is on the other link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Alternative_distribution_options/Sideloading_add-ons  
  
I used the registry method from the above link, because I couldn't even download the xpi file (seems like they disabled downloading from other browsers).  
  
Also there's a note:  
>To install an add-on for all users of a Windows computer, see Installation using the Windows registry.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of launching the `.xpi` installer, copy the `.xpi` file into a *standard extension folder*

- Global (x64) `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{appID}.xpi`
- Global (x86) `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{appID}.xpi`
- Per user `%AppData%\Mozilla\Extensions\{appID}\`

where the `{appID}` must be the application ID of a [signed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution) Firefox add-on.

Comment: How do I get the {addID}?

Comment: Never mind, installed using other manual.